# Python - Beginner Level - User input and while Loop combination

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I have did a little research around "Google", "YouTube", "Facebook" and "Stack Overflow" and I haven't found what I was looking for. So, I need your guidance. :)

I want program to ask user input "PASSWORD" and every time user inputs wrong password the program asks password again, and again, and again until user
types the correct password. Let's say that the password is as simple as "abc123".

So, I start the program and it asks to input: "PASSWORD: ". If user types "abc123" then program prints "GOOD PASSWORD". If user types anything what is not "abc123" then program prints "BAD PASSWORD". As simple as that.. for now.

My best attempt:

```
#SECTION1_ASKING
passwordInput=input('PASSWORD: ')
password='abc123'
while password == passwordInput:
    print('GOOD PASSWORD')
    break 
else:
    print('BAD PASSWORD')
    passwordInput=input('PASSWORD: ')

#SECTION2_RE-ASKING
while False:
    while password == paswordInput:
        print('GOOD PASSWORD')
    else:
        print('BAD PASSWORD')
        passwordInput=input('PASSWORD: ')
```

but I either make password asked once or twice or I stuck in **Infinite while Loop**.

Comment: You say two answers both worked, but one used `raw_input()`, which is Python 2, and one used `input()`, which is Python 3 (the Python 2 version of `input()` has a different use).  Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: `while` and `for` are looping constructs, it seems you are mistaking them with `if` or at least mixing those up, because they all can be combined with `else`. BTW, one advise: Write a plan in plain language first, so that anyone could understand it and follow it even without any programming knowledge. Keep this plan in the comments of your code.

Comment: I tried them both. I am using Python 3.x. I know that "raw_input()" is "input()" in Python 3.x, so I changed that part before I ran the code.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can watch the execution of small programs in a debugger to understand, what went wrong. There are online tools for this as well like [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: Well, for what I understand as a beginner, `if` runs code for once, `while` runs code over and over again, `for` runs code certain amount of times, and `else` just runs code instead of condition that is set on `if`, `while` or `for` code. Since I have an answer of my issue I going to analyze my mistake deeper. I feel that I need to practice more on these(`if`, `while`, `for`) and get comfortable using them before I move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
passwordInput=raw_input('PASSWORD: ')
password='abc123'
while True:
    if password == passwordInput:
        print('GOOD PASSWORD')
        break 
    else:
        print('BAD PASSWORD')
        passwordInput=raw_input('PASSWORD: ')
```

Comment: Your welcome :) @simeon9446 kindly mark it as the answer if it solves your query

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below in few lines.

```
password='abc123'
while(True):
    passwordInput=input('PASSWORD: ')
    if(passwordInput==password):
        print("Good password")
        break
    else:
        print("Bad password")
```

Comment: @simeon9446 Do you now know why your code didn't behave like you wanted it to?

Comment: Why the parentheses around the conditions?

Comment: @ifconfig Honestly, not really. It's like what I though that the program would do and what the program actually did went in similar but not exact direction. Whose fault - mine, because I gave wrong instructions to the program. Why? Because I lack knowledge and understanding. I am really "raw" in Python _(several days of actual usage)_ :) Now I'm using **PythonTutor** to analyze mistakes, and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
password = 'abc123'

while True:

    passwordInput = input('PASSWORD: ')

    if password == passwordInput:
        print('GOOD PASSWORD')
        break
    else:
        print('BAD PASSWORD')
```

How does that differ from yours?  For a start you can see that I only have one call to `input()`, that's generally a good idea because then you only need to check the password in one place.  Notice that I use `if` instead of `while` for the test.

In your second example you have `while False:`.  Can this ever be True?  No, so it won't get executed.

Notice as well that I use more whitespace.  That does not slow the program down, it makes it easier to read.  See also [PEP008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Now you have it working, just for fun, consider an improvement.  Normally you don't want the password to be visible when it is typed, but there's a module for that:  `getpass` - it's part of the standard library so you don't need to download anything.

Add `import getpass` to the top of your script. Instead of `input` use `getpass.getpass`, in the same place in the program, with the same parameters. Now it won't echo the password entered by the user.

`getpass` is the module name, `getpass` is also a function name, so `getpass.getpass('PASSWORD: ')` means execute the `getpass()` function in the `getpass` module.  We use lots of modules in Python, so its worth getting used to using them.  You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html), note there is also a `getpass.getuser()` to play with.

Comment: Oh..wow! That's really impressive. How about allowing to enter bad password certain amount of times? Is that very complex to do?

Comment: No, that's simple.  Just initialise a count variable to zero at the start, then increment it (`count += 1`) each time you ask for the password.  You then need an extra check (`if`) to see if the limit is exceeded.  More or less a Python 101 exercise.

Comment: By the way, next time you ask a question here consider if you really need that first paragraph.  It doesn't add anything and does not make people more willing to help.  What makes people help is to show the effort you tried yourself, which you did.